# Build Xcode Framework using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with an iOS project that produces a Framework directory at the root of the project when I execute Product -> Build For -> Running in Xcode.  I need to be able to automate this process on the command line presumably using xcodebuild.  However, I can't seem to determine the correct set of parameters to make this happen.  Any insight into how to run this same scenario without the GUI?  Do I have to look at using lipo?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the generic script I created.  It creates a framework with combined device and simulator binaries.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts s:w: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        s) scheme=${OPTARG};;
        w) workspace="-workspace ${OPTARG}.xcworkspace";;
    esac
done

if [ -z "$scheme" ]
then
      echo "$(basename $BASH_SOURCE) -- build XCFramework"
      echo ""
      echo "$(basename $BASH_SOURCE) -s scheme-name [ -w workspace0-name ]"
      echo ""
      echo "Run this script from the top-level directory of your framework."
      echo "The build result will be here: archives/<scheme-name>.xcframework"
      exit
fi

rm -rf archives/$scheme.xcframework

xcodebuild archive \
           $workspace \
           -scheme $scheme \
           -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
           -archivePath "archives/$scheme-Simulator" \
           SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
           BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild archive \
           $workspace \
           -scheme $scheme \
           -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
           -archivePath "archives/$scheme" \
           SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
           BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

cp -r archives/$scheme-Simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/. archives/simulator
cp -r archives/$scheme.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/. archives/ios

function GetUUID() {
    local arch=$1
    local binary=$2
    local dwarfdump_result=$(dwarfdump -u ${binary})
    local regex="UUID: (.*) \((.*)\)"
    if [[ $dwarfdump_result =~ $regex ]]; then
        local result_uuid="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        local result_arch="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        if [ "$result_arch" == "$arch" ]; then
            echo $result_uuid
        fi
    fi
}

BCSYMBOLMAP_UUID=$(GetUUID "arm64" "archives/$scheme.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/$scheme.framework/$scheme")

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
           -framework archives/ios/$scheme.framework \
           -debug-symbols ${PWD}/archives/$scheme.xcarchive/dSYMs/$scheme.framework.dSYM \
           -debug-symbols "${PWD}/archives/$scheme.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/${BCSYMBOLMAP_UUID}.bcsymbolmap" \
           -framework archives/simulator/$scheme.framework \
           -debug-symbols ${PWD}/archives/$scheme-Simulator.xcarchive/dSYMs/$scheme.framework.dSYM \
           -output archives/$scheme.xcframework

cd archives
rm -rf $scheme-Simulator.xcarchive $scheme.xcarchive ios simulator
```

Comment: How we can use this script? I mean this script adds in the run script in the build phases.

Comment: No, you must run this script from the command line.